# how to convert pandas str.split call to to dask

Tags: dask

I have a dask data frame where the index is a string which looks like this:

```
12/09/2016 00:00;32.0046;-106.259
12/09/2016 00:00;32.0201;-108.838
12/09/2016 00:00;32.0224;-106.004
```

(its basically a string encoding the datetime;latitude;longitude of the row)

I'd like to split that while still in the dask context to individual columns representing each of the fields.

I can do that with a pandas dataframe as:

```
df['date'], df['Lat'], df['Lon'] = df.index.str.split(';', 2).str
```

But that doesn't work in dask for several of the attempts I've tried.  If I directly substitute the df for a dask df I get the error:

```
'Index' object has no attribute 'str'
```

If I use the column name instead of index as:

```
forecastDf['date'], forecastDf['Lat'], forecastDf['Lon'] = forecastDf['dateLocation'].str.split(';', 2).str
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'StringAccessor' object is not iterable
```

Here is an runnable example of this working in Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dateLocation'] = ['12/09/2016 00:00;32.0046;-106.259','12/09/2016   00:00;32.0201;-108.838','12/09/2016 00:00;32.0224;-106.004']
df = df.set_index('dateLocation')
df['date'], df['Lat'], df['Lon'] = df.index.str.split(';', 2).str
df.head()
```

Here is the error I get if I directly convert that to dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
dd['date'], dd['Lat'], dd['Lon'] = dd.index.str.split(';', 2).str
>>TypeError: 'StringAccessor' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your example in Pandas and having a hard time.  Can you provide a tiny copy-pastable example of this working in Pandas?

Comment: I've updated the post with a pastable working example in pandas.  Thanks!

Comment: You ever solve this? I'm trying to do `ddf['col'].str[:-1]` with no success...

Comment: I did figure it out and have submitted my answer.

Comment: Dask arrays do not support yourarray['newcol'] = some_series - type assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure the column is string dtype

```
forecastDD['dateLocation'] = forecastDD['dateLocation'].astype('str')
```

Then you can use this to split in dask

```
splitColumns = client.persist(forecastDD['dateLocation'].str.split(';',2))
```

You can then index the columns in the new dataframe splitColumns and add them back to the original data frame.

```
forecastDD = forecastDD.assign(Lat=splitColumns.apply(lambda x: x[0], meta=('Lat', 'f8')), Lon=splitColumns.apply(lambda x: x[1], meta=('Lat', 'f8')), date=splitColumns.apply(lambda x: x[2], meta=('Lat', np.dtype(str))))
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do it without calling compute and creating the temp dataframe.

Comment: Its possible that this could be achieved more simply. One might explore expanding on this method - a single assignment case:
dd = dd.assign(**{'date':dd.index.str.split(';',n=1).str[0]})
dd.compute()

Answer (score 5):

```
forecastDf['date'] = forecastDf['dateLocation'].str.partition(';')[0]
forecastDf['Lat'] = forecastDf['dateLocation'].str.partition(';')[2]
forecastDf['Lon'] = forecastDf['dateLocation'].str.partition(';')[4]
```

Let me know if this works for you!